# sqlite android Update with punctation

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with a query
this is my sqllite table

```
CREATE_CONFIG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Config + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_VersioneAPP + " TEXT"
            + ")";
```

where

```
 private static final String TABLE_Config = "Configurazioni";
 private static final String KEY_VersioneAPP = "VersioneAPP";
```

I want to update "VersioneAPP" and I make a query like this :-

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_Config + " SET " + seleziona + " = ?",
            new String[] { NuovaVersione });
```

I tried also

```
String selezionata = "UPDATE " + TABLE_Config + " SET (" + seleziona + ") = ('"+ NuovaVersione+"')";
db.execSQL(selezionata);
```

NuovaVersione is a string as 10.2.3 or 1.2
If I make the query with NuovaVersione=1.2 it work.
But if I try with 10.2.3 I receive the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: it.asfautolinee.pulizie, PID: 15890
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{it.asfautolinee.pulizie/it.asfautolinee.pulizie.Login}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".3": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: UPDATE Configurazioni SET VersioneAPP = 10.2.3
>
> > ###########################################################  Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing
> >
> > database.(near ".3": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE
> >     Configurazioni SET VersioneAPP = 10.2.3)

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update "VersioneAPP" and I make a query like this db.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_Config + " SET " + seleziona + " = ?", new String[] { NuovaVersione });

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` to run a raw non-query SQL statement.

`rawQuery()` only compiles the SQL but does not run it (it is only run when the returned `Cursor` is moved). `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL but cannot return a result.

The syntax error is because you're not quoting a string literal and it gets interpreted as a numeric literal. Just use `?` variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried this  db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_Config + " SET " + seleziona + " = ?",
                new String[] { NuovaVersione });   but I have the same problem. Can you write me the right query please.

Comment: `execSQL()` bind args are `Object[]` not `String[]`. But you should not be getting "the same problem"

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + columnname + "=" + valuetoupdate + " WHERE " + conditioncolumn+ "=?",
                    new String[] {valueofcondition may be id});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 1.2 is accepted but not 10.2.3 is that a number is expected if the value is not quoted 1.2 is a valid numeric 10.2.3 is not.

However, I'd suggest using the recommended SQLiteDatabase update convenience method.

> It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected
>   rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String,
>   ContentValues), **update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])**, et
>   al, when possible. [execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update)

Your code would be :-

```
ContentValues cv = new Contentvalues();
cv.put(seleziona,NuovaVersione);
db.update(TABLE_Config,cv,null,null);
```

The convenience method will build the appropriate query. Additionally it will return the number of updates made as an int (e.g `int number_of_updates = db.update(TABLE_Config,cv,null);`) [update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update)